# add one column to table with value against the Other Columns Specific Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am Having Below Mention Table Where I want to Add column by query which will add one column to table with value against the Other Columns Specific Values
Consider Following Table

```
Name     Toggle Value
 John           1
 Nyasa          0
 Albert         1
 Micheal        0
 Laura          1
 Leah           0
```

In this Table in Front Of 1 want Text As **ACTIVE** and In front of Zero(0) I want it As **INACTIVE** with Column Name Status.

Comment: Hint:  a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CASE statement in your query .

```
SELECT Name ,Togglevalue, Case WHEN Togglevalue=1 THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'INACTIVE' END as Status
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working Fine

Comment: You are welcome.. mark it as a right answer if the solution helped you..

Comment: Yes I marked Can you help me with another issue I Am Facing Please Do the needful if possible   click on the link below  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284596/date-and-time-formatting-in-vb-net-and-sql-server

Comment: Please Check the link i also added table format in that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284596/date-and-time-formatting-in-vb-net-and-sql-server